# Mongo DB query at least one property but preferred more ideally all

Tags: json, mongodb, filtering

```
     "structure":{  
            "country":{  
               "name":"Some Country"
            },
            "city":{  
               "name":"Some City"
            },
            "building":{  
               "name":"Some Building"
            },
            "floor":{  
               "name":""
            }
       }
```

I have a collection of object like above. I need to query to collection thus it results only with one item.

Query should include filter for all four fields: country, city, building and floor.

If there is a match for all four that is ideal scenario.

If there is no such object in the collection, the query should return item with 3 matches and one that is empty.

If there is no three than two matches and the other two should be empty.

And the same for matching only one field.

It is important that other fields that do not match be empty. Not any value that does not match but exclusively "" empty space.

How to write mongo query for this?

The query would work for me like this:

```
    db.structures.find({"some query that I do no know here"}: {
                 "Some Country", 
                 "Some City", 
                 "Some Building", 
                 "Some Floor"
              });
```

This query would return json object from above, but it in the collection was object:

```
"structure":{  
        "country":{  
           "name":"Some Country"
        },
        "city":{  
           "name":"Some City"
        },
        "building":{  
           "name":"Some Building"
        },
        "floor":{  
           "name":"Some Floor"
        }
   }
```

It would be returned because it has all four matches.

Comment: It would really go a long way if you could construct some test cases where you populate a test collection with some sample documents, present each test case with the expected output from the query with the sample documents.

Comment: @chridam please check the edits.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but still not sure if I got your problem correctly: so if the the floor name is "Some Floor" as one of the query values and the other three values have matches in the db, you are expecting the query to return the document with the floor name value as empty?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with only one query.  There's something like 14 different combinations of matches (1 way of matching all four, 3 ways of matching 3, 6 ways of matching 2, 4 ways of matching 1)

Comment: I think you are looking for the [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator in your query.

Comment: @chridam `$or` is insufficient - it wouldn't allow you to return only the exact match (if found)

Comment: @chridam yes that is correct. And only if floor name value is empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution that I came up with.

```
db.structures.findOne({$or:
                  [
                  {$and:[
                    {"country.name": "Some Country"},
                    {"city.name": "Some City"},
                    {"building.name": "Some Building"},
                    {"floor.name": "Some Floor"}]
                   },
                  {$and:[
                    {"country.name": "Some Country"},
                    {"city.name": "Some City"},
                    {"building.name": "Some Building"},
                    {"floor.name": ""}]
                  },
                  {$and:[
                    {"country.name": "Some Country"},
                    {"city.name": "Some City"},
                    {"building.name": ""},
                    {"floor.name": ""}]
                  },
                  {$and:[
                    {"country.name": "Some Country"},
                    {"city.name": ""},
                    {"building.name": ""},
                    {"floor.name": ""}]
                  }]
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I well understand your need...
To search data matching your 4 values, the request should look like this:

```
db.structures.find({
      "country.name":"Some Country", 
      "city.name":"Some City", 
      "building.name":"Some Building", 
      "floor.name":"Some Floor"
});
```

Comment: You have not understood the question.

Comment: If you could edit the query so it loads data if matching 3 values and 4th is "" and if matching 2 values and 3rd and 4th are ""

Comment: Even in SQL, i am not able to figure how to write such a request ? $or operator will not be sufficient.